# Can you use a select statement as well as manual entry with an insert statement?

Tags: sql, insert

I'm not very knowledagble with SQL and just have a general question.

If I am using an insert statement with a select statement, would i be able to also insert manual data or is it all 100% pulled from other tables?

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2)
select col1, col2
from table1, table2
where table1.col1 = 'test'
, '0'
```

My question is, there's two columns in this table and I only need to pull a value from one table, is it possible for me to manually add the value for the second column at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Just do like

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2)
select col1, '0'
from table1
where table1.col1 = 'test'
```